# Is this yellowing normal for a kalanchoe plant?

Tags: fleshy-leaves

This is the only yellow leaf and the plant is even sprouting out 4 new shoots. I keep the soil moist and let it dry then water again. I don't keep it in direct light. It's in a breeze way that's probably... 80 or so degrees. I'm in Texas where it's 100 outside.

[image: yellow leaf]

More pictures:
Front of the whole plant. 
[image: front plant]

Upclose of yellow leaf. 
[image: upclose]

Back of plant. 
[image: backside]

Hidden leaf turning yellow. 
[image: hidden]

Other parts of the plant. 
[image: broken]

[image: dark stem tips]

Comment: I'm not an expert on Kalanchoe's, but that certainly does not look right to me.  I'd cut it off.

Comment: Well this is kinda a succulent so the leave pop of kinda easy. This is the only one doing this and I'm scared that if I take it off.. What ever is wrong will attack another leaf.

Comment: Oh my, you need to learn that plants are far tougher and more interesting than what you are imagining.  Go ahead and take the leaf off.  At the main stem.  What that leaf is trying to tell you concerns a few other factors...how you water, what you fertilize with and why you add fertilizer, what soil this guy gets to live in and DRAINAGE.  One leaf like this MEANS NOTHING.  Pics of the entire plant and specs on your maintenance, management are necessary!

Comment: @stormy I'll add stuff tomorrow, it's late now.

Comment: @Tsuk: Hello! Ah, this Kalanchoe... For a while, I watered it less frequently if the leaves were firm and found some miracle grow fertilizer for the soil because it had been in the same soil for a long time. As a few people suggested, I did end up removing the leaf carefully too as it one of the oldest leaves on the plant. From then on it grew rather well. I actually, ended up cutting the tops off and have transplanted them into another container. So, the original looks really bare right now, while it's growing new sprouts. If you'd like I can show you pictures of them currently somehow.

Answer (score 4):

That leaf is on it's way out.  Plants discard leaves for various reasons:

- overwatering: older leaves are discarded while still plump with water, usually seen with yellowing and sometimes the spotting from virus/fungus/bacteria
- underwatering: leaves wither and die from the tip back.  They are dry and papery.
- leaves accumulate waste products as they age and older leaves are discarded when they are no longer efficient

Remove this leaf cleanly at the stem and watch for more symptoms.  If more older leaves start yellowing cut back on the water.  This is most common cause of death of interior potted plants.

Comment: I will try this. I've not been watering it much.. And the leaves are all thick and firm. I'm hoping that is is just because it's an old leaf